# AdalAngular can work ncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-active-directory

i try to use AdalAngular in angularJS but it can inject the modul .do you have en idee to solve that i try to work with the AZUreAD :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [ 'ngRoute', 'AdalAngular' ]);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', function($routeProvider,
        $httpProvider, adalProvider,    $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller : "loginController",
        templateUrl : "login.html"
    }
```

the file d'index  : the load of the file work but u have this error ncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Car parks</title>
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link
    href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <script src="modul/angularJS-1.2.32/angular.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="modul/angularJS-1.2.32/angular-resource.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="modul/angularJS-1.2.32/angular-route.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="modul/angularJS-1.2.32/adal.min.js"></script>
    <script src="modul/angularJS-1.2.32/adal-angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/myApp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/loginController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/UserController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/SecretaryController.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/AdminController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/SearchCarController.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/controller/UserAddController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/AddCarController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/controller/ProfilController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/ValidateController.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/LogoutController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have **$locationProvider**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', '$locationProvider',
            function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/', {
                    controller: "loginController", templateUrl: "login.html"
                });
            }]);
```